# Call WordPress filter action with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using the [Give](https://givewp.com/) plugin for WordPress. They have a proof-of-concept pluginn that allows adding a fee at checkout https://github.com/WordImpress/Give-Snippet-Library/blob/master/form-customizations/basic-fees.php

This works as expected and have no problems there, but what I'm trying to do is make the fee optional so the donor can choose from the front-end whether or not they want to add that fee.

Here's the part of the code that creates the new donation amout:

```
function give_basic_fees_add_fee( $sanitized_amount ) {
    $fee_percentage = (int) give_get_option( 'basic_fee_percentage' );
    $fee            = $sanitized_amount * ( $fee_percentage / 100 );
    $new_total      = $fee + $sanitized_amount;
    return $new_total;
}
add_filter( 'give_donation_total', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee', 1, 1 );
```

What I'm trying to do is call this with Ajax. I tried the below, which is not working:

JS:

```
//...
//Use Ajax to see if user checked fee box before submitting
//I've already confirmed this part of the script is loading in the footer.
            function check_for_fees(){
                var checked;
                if($('#gateway-fee').is(':checked')){
                    checked=true;
                }
                else {
                    checked=false;
                }
                var data = {
                    'action': 'give_basic_fees_add_fee',
                    'checked': checked
                }
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            }
```

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_axaj_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
add_action('wp_axaj_nopriv_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
function give_basic_fees_add_fee( $sanitized_amount ) {

    /*I just want to alert "Checked" so I know it's working, and create
    additional conditional code depending on the value of "checked".*/
    $checked        = intval($_POST['checked']);
    echo $checked;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, and that should be the reason it doesn't work.

Instead of typing

```
add_action('wp_axaj_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee'); add_action('wp_axaj_nopriv_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
```

type:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
```

Default Wordpress prefix for ajax calls is wp_ajax, not wp_axaj.

Comment: That was it! I noticed this last night and forgot to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi try this may help you.**

```
add_action('wp_axaj_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
add_action('wp_axaj_nopriv_give_basic_fees_add_fee', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee');
function give_basic_fees_add_fee() {
    /*I just want to alert "Checked" so I know it's working, and create
    additional conditional code depending on the value of "checked".*/
    $checked        = intval($_POST['checked']);
    echo $checked;
//<b>Add exit here otherwise it will give zero along with response.</b>
exit;
}
```